# How to set text height in a textblock using textpos in Beamer?

Tags: text, beamerposter, height, textpos

I'm using the textpos package with Beamer in order to put some text at the bottom right corner of a slide.
Despite having read the package instructions, I fail to understand how to set the text height of the textblock.
The relative instructions say:

> There is an alternative, starred, form of the {textblock} environment. In the
>   argument to the {textblock*} environment, the block width, and the block position
>   (but not the specification of the block reference point) are given as absolute
>   dimensions, rather than as numbers in units of the horizontal and vertical modules.
>   Thus

```
\begin{textblock*}{hhsizei}[hhoi,hvoi](hhposi,hvposi)
text...
\end{textblock*}
```

> produces a textblock of the given size, where this time hhsizei, hhposi and hvposi
>   are absolute dimensions, but hhoi and hvoi are still pure-number offsets (that is,
>   fractions of the width and height of the textblock), as above.
>
> Each {textblock} environment takes up zero space on the page (which means,
>   by the way, that it cannot detect that it’s overprinting or being overprinted), so
>   you can (and typically will) use several of the environments in a row to scatter
>   text all over the page.
>
> The package is compatible with the calc package, so that you may use calc-style
>   expressions when specifying lengths. Thus

```
\usepackage{calc}
\textblockorigin{56.9055pt-10mm}{0pt+1cm}
\begin{textblock*}{10mm+14cm}(0.3cm*5,10\TPVertModule+5mm)
6
text. . .
\end{textblock*}
```

> Note that you can only use calc-style expressions where you would specify a length
>   with units, such as the width and location arguments of {textblock*} or the
>   arguments to \textblockorigin – you can’t use them when specifying a length
>   in units of the horizontal and vertical modules, such as in the width and location
>   arguments to the (unstarred) {textblock} environment.

However, I have to admit I don't fully understand these instructions.
I would like thte text in the textblock to be a bit smaller than the normal text.

Here is a mwe:

```
    \documentclass[17pt,t]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setbeameroption{hide notes}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone}

\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\newcommand\FrameText[1]{%
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0pt,\textheight)
    \raggedleft #1\hspace{.5em}
  \end{textblock*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]{Plops}
Plops plops plops
\FrameText{Textblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I think this might be a beamer question rather than a textpos one (since I dimly remember that the font-size commands work a little unexpectedly in beamer), but changing `#1` to `{\tiny #1}` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have somewhat solved the problem by adding a size tag on an individual \FramText (but I know there is a way to generalize the text size in the settings of \newcommand\FrameText) :

```
\documentclass[17pt,t]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setbeameroption{hide notes}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone}

\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\newcommand\FrameText[1]{%
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0pt,\textheight)
    \raggedleft #1\hspace{.5em}
  \end{textblock*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]{Plops}
Plops plops plops
\FrameText{\footnotesize Textblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```